# How do I write string to longvarchar in pervasive larger than 32k?

Tags: vb6, pervasive

Application written in VB6. DB is Pervasive v9.5.

Currently works:

```
Public Sub Save()   
    if rs.State = adStateOpen Then
         rs.AddNew
         SetFields rs
         rs.Update
    End If
end sub

Public Sub SetFields(rs as ADODB.Recordset)
    rs!Name = strName
    StrToField strReport rs!Report
    StrToField strResponse rs!Response
end sub

Public Sub StrToField(ByVal str As String, fld As ADODB.Field)
    Dim Data As String
    Dim StrSize As Long, CharsRead As Long

    ' for field of LONVARCHAR type only
    If fld.Type = adLongVarChar Then
        StrSize = Len(str)
        Do While StrSize <> CharsRead
            If StrSize - CharsRead < BLOCK_SIZE_LONGVARCHAR Then
                Data = Mid(str, CharsRead + 1, StrSize - CharsRead)
                CharsRead = StrSize
            Else
                Data = Mid(str, CharsRead + 1, BLOCK_SIZE_LONGVARCHAR)
                CharsRead = CharsRead + BLOCK_SIZE_LONGVARCHAR
            End If
            fld.AppendChunk Data
        Loop
     Else
        ' do something
     End If
 End Sub

Const BLOCK_SIZE_LONGVARCHAR = 4096
```

This works fine until my report or response variable is larger than 32000 characters. I receive this error message when rs.update is called:

**"[Pervasive][ODBC Client Interface] String length exceeds column length Parameter #15. Data truncated."**

Can anyone point me in the right direction or let me know if I am missing something. Pervasive Longvarchar max size should be 2GB.

Thanks,
Graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works form me using PSQL v11 (I don't have v9.5).

```
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Set conn = New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "demodata"
conn.Open
Dim sql As String
Dim cmd As New ADODB.Command
cmd.ActiveConnection = conn
cmd.CommandText = "insert into lvc (f2) values (?)"
Dim parm As New ADODB.Parameter
parm.Name = "f2"
Dim longstring As String
Open "c:\longdata.txt" For Input As #1
Do While Not EOF(1)
   Line Input #1, sNextLine
   'do something with it
   'add line numbers to it, in this case!
   sText = sText & sNextLine
Loop
longstring = sText
parm.Value = longstring
cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("param1", adLongVarChar, adParamInput, Len(longstring), longstring)
cmd.Execute
conn.Close
MsgBox "done"
```

Basically, you would use parameterized queries rather than the .AddNew method.